# Share Android library in github

Tags: android, github

I developed an android library. I have repository in Github and pushed my code, even I made Readme.md for my codes. The only thing I have problem with, is I do not know what to put in below parts so that users have access to codes without downloading library and just add to dependencies, what should I place instead of dots?

```
repositories {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compile('...')
}
```

Comment: i'm nob in Github, could you please answer me instead of voting down?

Comment: The fact that you have put your code on Github means you have already shared the code (if it's a public repository). I think you're downvoted because your question is phrased wrong. You want to make a gradle / maven repository for your code -  that is your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Check this two links. These are the best tutorials I found.

[one](https://www.virag.si/2015/01/publishing-gradle-android-library-to-jcenter/)

[two](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en)

Comment: thank you. uestcfei posted one of the before by I did this by reading both of them ;)

Comment: can pick as answer if you like.

Answer (score 2):

If you've pushed your code to GitHub then sharing your Android library (aar) is easy with [JitPack](https://jitpack.io).

Your users will just need to add the repository to their build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

and then your GitHub repository as dependency:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    compile 'com.github.YourUsername:Repo:Release'
}
```

JitPack acts as a maven repository and can be used like Maven Central. The nice thing is that you don't have to upload your library. Behind the scenes JitPack will check out the code from GitHub and compile it. As you publish a new release on GitHub it becomes available for others to use.

There is also [a guide](https://jitpack.io/docs/ANDROID/) on how to prepare an Android project.

Answer (score 0):

you need to register an account in https://bintray.com ,and config your local file `gradle.properties` with your `BINTRAY_KEY` and `BINTRAY_USER`.for detail info ,please refers this [post](https://www.virag.si/2015/01/publishing-gradle-android-library-to-jcenter/) 。 Good luck !